# Decimal Format set zero digit

Tags: java

Can someone explain what's the use of setZeroDigit and how exactly does it works.
For e.g.

```
double d = 123456.7899;
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setZeroDigit('@');
symbols.setMinusSign('^');

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("-###,###.000",symbols);

System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

it prints ^ABC,DEF.GI@ , but i doesn't understand how it computes the output. I read javadocs but it's not much a help. One more thing my locale is en_US.

Comment: What output does it give you for various positive and negative numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `DecimalFormatSymbols` if you want to print numbers in some other language or locale, that doesn't use the usual set of symbols for things like the negative sign, the percentage sign, and so on. You might use `setZeroDigit` if you were printing numbers in Arabic, for example, which uses a dot for zero.

In your example, you've said "use `@` for zero", and that's exactly what has happened.

However, there's slightly more to it.  The symbols used for 1, 2, 3 etc are assumed to be the symbols immediately following the symbol for 0, in whatever character encoding  you use.  It just so happens that the symbols following @ in the usual character encodings are A, B, C etc.

The format that you specified requires rounding to three decimal places, so `-123456.7899` becomes `-123456.79`, which is then printed using the symbols `@, A, B ... I` in place of `0, 1, 2 ... 9`.  You also specified that it should use `^` in place of `-`, using `setMinusSign`.

Comment: I am interested to know how it generates out ^ABC,DEF.GI@

Comment: You asked for only 3 decimal digits, so -123456.7899 is rounded to -123456.790 alias ^ABC,DEF.GI@